# Can i write java code in processings IDE?

Tags: processing

When I google it I find tutorials on how to use Processing in eclipse. I was wondering if there was a way to do the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Processing is written in Java, so you can write Java in Processing.

You shouldn't have to do anything special. It should pretty much "just work" out of the box.

Here's a small example:

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

void draw(){}

void mousePressed(){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hello world");
}
```